# Why don't I have permissions to view the contents of a mounted ext4 partition (live-USB boot)?

Tags: permissions, live-usb, ssd, partitioning

Booting a Mint live-usb on an Ubuntu 16.04 system, as one of the steps to move the OS from sdb6 (HHD) to sda1 (SSD).

When trying to view the folder of sda1 partition a pop up goes:

```
The folder contents could not be displayed.
You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "5089a00c-bc93-4d9e-b7c0-d84e84e4d305".
```

Nevertheless I could cp the contents of sdb6 to sda1.

Still the partition icon appears with the symbol "x" ([partitions icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMZOe.png))

mount:

```
/cow on / type overlay (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sdc on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=mint)
/dev/sda1 on /media/mint/5089a00c-bc93-4d9e-b7c0-d84e84e4d305 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/mint/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb6 on /media/mint/b023034d-143c-4c02-8b4f-4d737eb3857f type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

id:

```
uid=999(mint) gid=999(mint) groups=999(mint),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),107(lpadmin),110(sambashare)
```

ls -ald /media/mint

```
drwxr-x---+ 4 root root 80 Apr  7 21:22 /media/mint
```

ls -ald /media/mint/5089a00c-bc93-4d9e-b7c0-d84e84e4d305

```
drwx------ 4 1000 1000 4096 Apr  7 14:00 /media/mint/5089a00c-bc93-4d9e-b7c0-d84e84e4d305
```

Comment: Please post the output of the `mount` and `id` command

Comment: updated in the body

Comment: Add the output of `ls -ald /media/mint` and `ls -ald /media/mint/5089a00c-bc93-4d9e-b7c0-d84e84e4d305`

Comment: updated with the requested output

Answer (score 1):

I finally re-created the partitions in the SSD directly from the USB/booted system. Then I had no permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the current user to the group `disk`. It gives them access to sdX and other mounted drives.

**EDIT :** You should better use a program like `gparted` to move one of your partitions from a HDD to a SSD ....

Comment: Added with usermod (then checked with adduser: user 'mint' is already a user of 'disk'). logged out and in.  Still the same

Comment: What is the comman you are using to mount your drive ? Do you use sudo ?

Comment: Edited answer, btw

Comment: I mounted just by clicking on the relevant 115Gb Volume icon. The same way I mounted other Volumes, which are accessible